# "Fatal error: Call to undefined function" resulting in particular local server, but ran well in others'

Tags: php, function, xampp, wamp, tcpdf

I'm developing a PHP application which generating reports to PDF
Right now I'm facing some troubles
I'm working from my own computer with `XAMPP Server` and the code ran well
But when I copied the codes to my office's `WAMP5 Version 1.6.5 Server` I got errors
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function array_fill_keys() in D:\wwwroot\tcpdf\include\tcpdf_fonts.php on line 1848`

I went to that troubled line and removed it, but another `Fatal error: Call to undefined function` occured
Is there something wrong with my `WAMP5` configuration?
Thanks

Comment: What php versions are running on the servers?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php  (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0)  is it possible to have less version?

Comment: What does `echo phpversion();` output?

Comment: in my computer `5.4.16` in office server `5.1.6`

Comment: oke guys, thank you very much... i'm new to PHP programming and you are all so awesome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of php is to old... as Royal Bg suspected.
Either upgrade to 1.6.6 for php 5.2. But if there is no reason to use such an old version switch to something less than 7 years old :)

see:
http://sourceforge.net/p/wampserver/news/?source=navbar